# unzipping a folder throws error: End-of-central-directory signature not found

Tags: command-line, software-installation, zip, unzip

```
$ unzip ABC.zip
Archive:  ABC.zip
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of ABC.zip or
        ABC.zip.zip.zip, and cannot find ABC.zip.zip.ZIP, period.
```

How to unzip ABC.zip folder? Folder contains sub-folders and tex files.
My friends are able to unzip the same folder while my system throws the above error message.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that the file on your system is at least the same size as on your friends'? This message is typical of truncated ZIP files.